# Search in recent files

Tags: helm, search, grep, helm-grep

I use `helm-recentf` to receive the list of recent files.
I would like to have an opportunity to search over the list of recently viewed files. 
Can I do it with `grep` or `helm-swoop`? Is there any other way?

UPDATE:
Lets say I have the list of recent files, and I want to find all occurrences of `blah` in all recent files. How would I do this?

Comment: You can search the list using the `helm-recentf` command, so I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do here.

Comment: You can also grep those files with `helm-recentf`, but you have to mark the files you want to search by pressing `M-a` to mark all files or `C-SPC` to mark them individually. With the files marked, press TAB to toggle the menu, choose the option "Grep Files" and enter your input.

Comment: Thank you. It works with `C-SPC` but not with `M-a`, it seems that `M-a` works only for buffers. How can I mark all the files in `helm-recentf`?

Comment: You're probably trying to do this from helm-mini, in which case there's an extra step: 1. `M-x helm-mini` 2. `C-o` 3. `M-a`. Otherwise, 1. `M-x helm-recentf` 2. `M-a` is all you need.

Comment: This decision works only for buffers in `M-x helm-mini`.
1. `M-x helm-mini` 2. `C-o` 3. `M-a` -> only files in Buffers are marked.
Otherwise,
1. `M-x helm-recentf` 2. `M-a` -> `M-a is undefined`.
I try to comment all packages in my init file except for helm, but before mentioned issue repeats.

Comment: M-a is bound to `helm-mark-all`, and it does what it says, so I'm not sure what the problem is. Maybe try with emacs -Q or emacs-helm.sh (see [here](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/wiki/Bugs)).